# Set equal Size of images in scrollview : Loading from assets

Tags: android

[image]I loaded images from assets,and showed them in scroll views, both in horizontal and vertiacal views separately. But Images size is not equal. They look different and awkward,as shown in left of the picture. I want them all to be in same size.How do I get this? Here is my code:

```
XML:
   <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                    <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollViewlay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                  <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="67dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/imagesView" >

                </LinearLayout>

                        </ScrollView>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
    if(((LinearLayout) scrollV).getChildCount() > 0){ 
                    ((LinearLayout) scrollV).removeAllViews(); 
                }
                for(int j=0;j<images[(Integer) v.getTag()].length;j++){


                      try {
                       Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromAsset(images[(Integer) v.getTag()][j]);
                       ImageView image = new ImageView(PhotoView.this);
                       image.setImageBitmap(bm);

                       LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams  = new    
                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams(133, 89);
                       if(j==0){
                       layoutParams.setMargins(0, 2, 0, 2);
                       }
                       else{

                           layoutParams.setMargins(0,0 ,0 , 2);
                       }
                        image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                       scrollV.addView(image);

                      } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                }
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) throws IOException
{
    AssetManager assetManager =getAssets();
    InputStream istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    return bitmap;
 }
```

Comment: When you don't set any height or width of the images they automatically resize themselves to their original size. Try giving the some Height and Width values, or set them to fill their container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

eventually

```
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

The problem is in first case, the aspect ratio will not bee kept.
In second case, the some images can be cropped.

But they should have the same size

Answer (score 1):

You can set the image scale using:

`image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY)`

But, I'd suggest don't use image resources of different sizes in the first place, if eventually you want to show them uniformly. Using the above scaling code will make some of the images look distorted. The best way is, patiently design the resources for hdmi, xdpi, ldpi and mdpi screen types, and store resources for each screen type in it's own folder. Additionally, use the 9-patch tool that comes with the Android SDK to pre-scale your resources before using them. This reduces  the memory impact of resources, and when scaling for different screen sizes, they won't be distorted.

I know it takes time to do all that resource design work, but it's worth the effort for the quality of media provided for different screens.